# Selecting new rows for a given date

Tags: sql, database, join, firebird

I have two columns, customer_name and invoice_date, in a table called bookkeeping.

All customers invoiced are entered in bookkeeping with the appropriate value in "invoice_date" column. The values in the "customer_name" column will most definitely have duplicates, but the "invoice_date" column will not (as only one customer is invoiced at a time).

Assuming the table has data for a month, how do I get a list of customers from the bookkeeping table that are new on a given date. Example, assuming table has data for entire month of March, how do I get all customers that were first invoiced on March 17th, excluding any customers that were invoiced on prior (or future) dates?

I am using a Firebird database.

Comment: Is this the correct SQL for this?

Comment: `select distinct customer_name 
       from bookkeeping 
       where         cast(invoice_date as date) = 'march 29, 2012'
                     and customer_name not in (select distinct customer_name from bookkeeping where cast(invoice_date as date) < 'march 29, 2012');`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  b.customer_name

FROM
  bookkeeping b LEFT JOIN bookkeeping b2
    ON b.customer_name = b2.customer_name
      AND b.invoice_date <> b2.invoice_date
WHERE
  b.invoice_date = '17.03.2012'
  AND
  b2.customer_name IS NULL
```